# Subsampling a multidimensional array in Julia

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have an array of size 330x534x223 containing a distribution of values, like a 3d image. It's size is prohibitively large for my purposes, so I'm looking to resample it by a factor of 20 in each dimension.

Is there any conceivable way to do this? I've tried checking the docs

Thank you

Comment: Check out the [JuliaImages Organization](https://github.com/JuliaImages). They have a ton of toolboxes for working with images, and something for this must be in there.

Comment: `subsample = [big[i,j,k] for i=1:20:size(big,1),j=1:20:size(big,2),k=1:20:size(big,3)]` might be one way (I've called the array `big`).

Comment: @DanGetz What is the advantage of this over `B[1:20:end, 1:20:end, 1:20:end]`? It seems both more verbose and slower.

Comment: @DNF No advantage. Just more explicit and came first to my mind, also, no confusion regarding view vs. copy semantics.

Comment: View vs copy I get, but I don't think it's more explicit. Maybe my Matlab background is coming through, but I thought the slicing syntax was so obvious, it confused me that no one mentioned it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're thinking in terms of "thumbnail images," then just taking every 20th element may not be satisfying. For something that will simultaneously smooth and subsample with very good performance, I recommend `restrict` from JuliaImages (which cuts by a factor of 2, and you can call it repeatedly).

Comment: Yes, this is the sort of approach I was after. Perhaps subsampling was a poor choice of words.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```julia
julia> subsample(a, n) = getindex(a, (indices(a,i)[1:n:end] for i=1:ndims(a))...)
subsample (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a = reshape(1:10^6, (100,100,100));

julia> subsample(a, 50)
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  1  5001
 51  5051

[:, :, 2] =
 500001  505001
 500051  505051
```

This should also work for arrays with unconventional indexing like `OffsetArrays`.

For large arrays, the overhead of this implementation compared to the direct indexing with ranges is negligible.

**Edit:**
A type stable version:

```julia
subinds(n, inds) = (first(inds)[1:n:end], subinds(n, Base.tail(inds))...)
subinds(n, ::Tuple{}) = ()
subsample(a, n) = getindex(a, subinds(n, indices(a))...)
```